# Call Interface Method from Console Application

Tags: c#

I have a Web Application where I have the class:

```
public class PTPostalCodeService : IPTPostalCodeService
{

   private readonly IRepository<PTPostalCode> _ptPostalCodeRepository;

   public PTPostalCodeService(IRepository<PTPostalCode> ptPostalCodeRepository)
    {
        _ptPostalCodeRepository = ptPostalCodeRepository;
    }

   public PTPostalCodeDto GetPTPostalCode(int postalCode, int? postalCodeExtension)
    {
        PTPostalCode ptPostalCodeDomain = new PTPostalCode();

        ptPostalCodeDomain = _ptPostalCodeRepository.Get(
            filter: p => p.PostalCode == postalCode && (postalCodeExtension.HasValue == false || p.PostalCodeExtension == postalCodeExtension),
            includeProperties: "PTCouncil, PTCouncil.PTDistrict").FirstOrDefault();

        var ptPostalCodeDto = Mapper.Map<PTPostalCode, PTPostalCodeDto>(ptPostalCodeDomain);

        return ptPostalCodeDto;
    }
}
```

Now I need to access the methid GetPTPostalCode from a ConsoleApplication, any idea?

EDIT:

I have AutoFac to manage constructors:

```
// Repository
builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(Repository<>))
            .As(typeof(IRepository<>))
            .InstancePerHttpRequest();
```

The interface of the Repository:

```
public interface IRepository<T> where T : class
```

Thanks.

Comment: Please remove the asp.net-mvc tag

Comment: why do I have to remove it?

Comment: Cause the question is not related to asp.net-mvc. That method could be located in any kind of project, it would not affect the situation (unless your question is not properly formulated, in which case, correct it and add the tag back)

Comment: it has gone, I don't know how....